# empty sql table only if it exists (not drop)

Tags: sql

How can I delete the contents of a table only if it exists? Preferably the sql statement should be standard and not oriented to any db.

Please notice that I do not want to drop a table if it exists, i.e.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo
```

PS: I have already checked truncate and delete but they don't fit the requirement if the table exists.

Comment: Makes no sense. Delete the contents of a table only if it is exists? For sure you cannot delete contents of a table that does not exists. How does delete or truncate not fit your requirements?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` does not usually change between different versions and is common in most databases, and to my best knowledge this is the most proper way to check whether a table exists in SQL:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_NAME = tableName ))
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM tableName
END
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, there is no standard for "if exists". Some databases support it, others do not, and will give you a syntax exception.